# Server connection issue with appium server

Tags: appium

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.9.0
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
(node:19484) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\chitr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\main.js:3
import {init as logsinkInit} from './logsink'; // this import needs to come first since it sets up global npmlog
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v20.11.1
Failed to create Appium session: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'LAPTOP-H5TLNT0T', ip: '172.20.10.2'
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'LAPTOP-H5TLNT0T', ip: '172.20.10.2'
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:536)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:268)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:161)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:90)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:102)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:109)
at aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.Configuration.AppiumConnection(Configuration.java:38)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:393)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:326)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:180)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1228)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1101)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpHandler,java.util.function.Supplier,long)
Build info: version: '4.19.0', revision: '5f9cec8963'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.9'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:137)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:176)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:237)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpHandler,java.util.function.Supplier,long)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2675)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:128)
... 36 more
FAILED: aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testLogin
java.lang.NullPointerException: The provided search context cannot be null
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:924)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.requireWebDriverReference(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:129)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:86)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:100)
at aenaontech.pageObjects.android.ElementLocators.(ElementLocators.java:25)
at aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testLogin(CallBookingExistingGuest.java:17)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:228)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:63)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:961)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:201)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1228)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1101)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testFutureBooking
java.lang.Throwable: Method aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testFutureBooking() on instance aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest@53fe15ff depends on not successfully finished methods
[aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testWithoutTable() on instance aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest@53fe15ff]
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:157)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1228)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1101)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testAddExistingGuest
java.lang.Throwable: Method aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testAddExistingGuest() on instance aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest@53fe15ff depends on not successfully finished methods
[aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testLogin() on instance aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest@53fe15ff]
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:157)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1228)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1101)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testWithoutTable
java.lang.Throwable: Method aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testWithoutTable() on instance aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest@53fe15ff depends on not successfully finished methods
[aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest.testAddExistingGuest() on instance aenaontech.RestaurantAdv.CreateReservationFlow.CallBookingExistingGuest@53fe15ff]
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:157)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1228)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1101)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

## ===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Skips: 3

## ===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 4, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 3

Why I am getting this error in my Appium TestNG code? I checked my configuration file and it is correct still I am facing this issue

I want to connect with the appium server